# Using RSC To Access Chat Messages with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am building a Teams chat-bot that looks at the history of messages in the current chat/channel whilst in conversation with the user.

My bot has been granted all the RSC (Resource-Specific Content) Permissions it needs (see image below)

[image: RSC Permissions]

Here is the relevant parts of the manifest:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifestVersion": "1.11",
    "id": "bd33f8b1-b593-433c-926e-44a27c1bd94a",
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    ...
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "e6d93739-a8ab-412d-a4f6-b6f514a3451a",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal",
                "groupchat"
              ],
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "supportsFiles": true
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "e6d93739-a8ab-412d-a4f6-b6f514a3451a",
        "resource": "https://RscBasedStoreApp",
        "applicationPermissions": [
            "TeamSettings.Read.Group",
            "ChannelMessage.Read.Group",
            "TeamSettings.Edit.Group",
            "ChannelSettings.ReadWrite.Group",
            "Channel.Create.Group",
            "Channel.Delete.Group",
            "TeamsApp.Read.Group",
            "TeamsTab.Read.Group",
            "TeamsTab.Create.Group",
            "TeamsTab.ReadWrite.Group",
            "TeamsTab.Delete.Group",
            "Member.Read.Group",
            "Owner.Read.Group",
            "ChatSettings.Read.Chat",
            "ChatSettings.ReadWrite.Chat",
            "ChatMessage.Read.Chat",
            "ChatMember.Read.Chat",
            "Chat.Manage.Chat",
            "TeamsTab.Read.Chat",
            "TeamsTab.Create.Chat",
            "TeamsTab.Delete.Chat",
            "TeamsTab.ReadWrite.Chat",
            "TeamsAppInstallation.Read.Chat",
            "OnlineMeeting.ReadBasic.Chat",
            "Calls.AccessMedia.Chat",
            "Calls.JoinGroupCalls.Chat",
            "TeamsActivity.Send.Chat"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Note**: the bot has permission to read messages in *chats* and *channels*.  Specifically, my problem affects *chats* and not *channels* (which I can get messages from fine).

In order to do this, I get a JWT token for the bot account, accessing the Graph API like so:

```
GraphServiceClient<?> gsc = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(u -> mac.getToken())
            .buildClient();
```

Next, I am using the Graph API to pull back these messages.  For messages in channels I can do:

```
gsc.teams("some group id")
            .channels("team id")
            .messages()
            .buildRequest(Collections.emptyList()).get()));
```

This works fine.

For chats, I am doing something like:

```
gsc.chats("29:13qY8hmfkJinH9-v7rYKjCNFHYFJXKbjqR-NyzyKzL694npelHJoq5HrVtqJLRYo79OYeHGQq-bhtJM5N-yKXyQ")
.messages()
.buildRequest().get()));
```

However, this time I get an error from the Graph API:

> [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for
> more details] com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error
> code: Forbidden Error message: Invoked API requires Protected API
> access in application-only context when not using Resource Specific
> Consent. Visit
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis for more
> details.
>
> GET
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/29:13qY8hmfkJinH9-v7rYKjCNFHYFJXKbjqR-NyzyKzL694npelHJoq5HrVtqJLRYo79OYeHGQq-bhtJM5N-yKXyQ/messages
> SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.6.0

I am at a loss to explain why querying channels works fine but querying chats fails.

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: What permission have you provided?

Comment: Hi @HunaidHanfee-MSFT - see the attached image.  I've provided all of them

Comment: I've added (most of) the manifest file in case that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a protected API and in order to use it you will first need to make a formal request to Microsoft Graph, asking for permissions to use the API without any user interaction

Here is the list of [protected APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis). You need to fill this [form](https://aka.ms/teamsgraph/requestaccess) to get the required permissions.

> To request access to these protected APIs, complete the following
> [request form](https://aka.ms/teamsgraph/requestaccess). We review access requests every Wednesday and deploy
> approvals every Friday, except during major holiday weeks in the U.S.
> Submissions during those weeks will be processed the following
> non-holiday week.

The other option would be to use delegated flow.

Comment: In the response back from the server it says: "Invoked API requires Protected API access in application-only context when not using Resource Specific Consent. ".  But I am attempting to use Resource Specific Content?

Comment: @Rob Moffat - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/rsc/resource-specific-consent#check-your-app-for-added-rsc-permissions-in-a-chat - Can you check if you are getting ChannelMessage.Read.Group and ChatMessage.Read.Chat in the response?